Enforce learning by adding explaination in quiz program
Title: Enforce learning by adding explaination in quiz program
I am making a quiz program. I wonder if I somebody can help me what to modify and how to add hints to my program.
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase


def get_ext(file_type):
    SAMPLE = {
            'Who is the founder of Microsoft?': ['Bill Gates', 'Bill Clinton', 'Jeff Bezos', 'Elon Musk'],
            'Who is the founder of Amazon?': ['Jeff Bezos', 'Bill Gates', 'Elon Musk', 'Joe Biden'],
            'Who created Linux?': ['Linus Torvalds', 'Elon Musk', 'Bill Gates', 'Mark Zuckerberg'] 
            }
    return locals()[file_type]

def startQuiz():
    try:
        questionnaire = get_ext("SAMPLE")
        tItems = (len(questionnaire))
            
    except:
        print ("Something is wrong")
   

    questionPerStudent = min(3, len(questionnaire))
    questionnaire = random.sample(list(questionnaire.items()), k=questionPerStudent)
    num_correct = 0
    currentQ = 0


    for num, (questionnaire, alternatives) in enumerate(questionnaire, start=1):
        print ("{}. {}".format(num,questionnaire))
        currentQ += 1           
        correct_answer = alternatives[0]
        labeled_alternatives = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, random.sample(alternatives, k=len(alternatives))))
        key_list  = list(labeled_alternatives.keys())
        val_list  = list(labeled_alternatives.values())
        position = val_list.index(str(correct_answer))
        keychoice = key_list[position]
        
        for label, alternative in labeled_alternatives.items():
            print(f"    {label}) {alternative}")

        while (answer_label := input("    Your answer is? ")) not in labeled_alternatives:
            print(f"    Please answer one of {', '.join(labeled_alternatives)}")
        answer = labeled_alternatives[answer_label]

        if answer == correct_answer:
            num_correct += 1
            print(f"Correct :  {keychoice}) {correct_answer}")
            
        else:
            print(f"Wrong Answer  :  {answer_label}) {answer}") 
            print(f"Correct Answer:  {keychoice}) {correct_answer}")



startQuiz()

Current Output:
1. Who is the founder of Microsoft?
    a) Jeff Bezos
    b) Bill Gates
    c) Elon Musk
    d) Bill Clinton
    Your answer is? a
Wrong Answer  :  a) Jeff Bezos
Correct Answer:  b) Bill Gates
2. Who is the founder of Amazon?
    a) Joe Biden
    b) Elon Musk
    c) Bill Gates
    d) Jeff Bezos
    Your answer is? a
Wrong Answer  :  a) Joe Biden
Correct Answer:  d) Jeff Bezos

I wanted to add an explaination in every question like:
'Who is the founder of Microsoft?': ['Bill Gates', 'Bill Clinton', 'Jeff Bezos', 'Elon Musk'] info = "this is the explaination",

What change do i need to add explaination in every question and create the output:
1. Who is the founder of Microsoft?
    a) Jeff Bezos
    b) Bill Gates
    c) Elon Musk
    d) Bill Clinton
    Your answer is? a
Wrong Answer  :  a) Jeff Bezos
Correct Answer:  b) Bill Gates

? this is the explaination


Why locals()[file_type] ?

For the purposes of this exercise it's perfectly reasonable to have your question "database" available globally. A well-structured list of dictionaries is ideal.
Here's a much simplified approach:
from random import sample
from string import ascii_lowercase

QUESTIONS = [
    {
        "q": "Who is the founder of Microsoft?",
        "a": ["Bill Gates", "Bill Clinton", "Jeff Bezos", "Elon Musk"],
        "e": "Microsoft explanation"
    },
    {
        "q": "Who is the founder of Amazon?",
        "a": ["Jeff Bezos", "Bill Gates", "Elon Musk", "Joe Biden"],
        "e": "Amazon explanation"
    },
    {
        "q": "Who created Linux?",
        "a": ["Linus Torvalds", "Elon Musk", "Bill Gates", "Mark Zuckerberg"],
        "e": "Linux explanation"
    }
]

def quiz():
    score = 0
    for i, question in enumerate(sample(QUESTIONS, k=len(QUESTIONS)), 1):
        print(f"{i}. {question["q"]}")
        a = question["a"]
        assert 0 < len(a) <= len(ascii_lowercase)
        r = ascii_lowercase[:len(a)]
        sq = sample(a, k=len(a))
        for c, q in zip(r, sq):
            print(f"    {c}) {q}")
        while True:
            response = input("    Your answer is? ")
            if response in set(r):
                if sq[r.index(response)] == a[0]:
                    print("Correct \U0001f600", question["e"])
                    score += 1
                else:
                    print("Wrong \U0001f615")
                break
            print("\aInvalid response")
    return score

if __name__ == "__main__":
    score = quiz()
    print(f"You scored {score} out of {len(QUESTIONS)}")


You could just make a dict() in your sample for every question. This way you can add as many items as you want to each question.
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import defaultdict


def get_ext(file_type):
    SAMPLE = {
        'Who is the founder of Microsoft?': {
            'options': ['Bill Gates', 'Bill Clinton', 'Jeff Bezos', 'Elon Musk'],
            'explanation': 'Bill Gates and Paul Allen founded Microsoft.'
        },
        'Who is the founder of Amazon?': {
            'options': ['Jeff Bezos', 'Bill Gates', 'Elon Musk', 'Joe Biden'],
            'explanation': 'Jeff Bezos founded Amazon.'
        },
        'Who created Linux?': {
            'options': ['Linus Torvalds', 'Ken Thompson', 'Dennis Ritchie', 'The Linux Organization'],
            'explanation': 'Linus Torvalds created Linux.'
        }
    }
    return locals()[file_type]


def startQuiz():
    try:
        questionnaire = get_ext("SAMPLE")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Something is wrong:", e)
        return

    question_per_student = min(3, len(questionnaire))
    selected_questions = random.sample(list(questionnaire.items()), k=question_per_student)
    num_correct = 0

    answers = defaultdict(list)
    for num, (question, data) in enumerate(selected_questions, start=1):
        options = data['options']
        explanation = data['explanation']

        print(f"{num}. {question}")
        correct_answer = options[0]
        labeled_alternatives = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, random.sample(options, k=len(options))))
        key_list = list(labeled_alternatives.keys())
        val_list = list(labeled_alternatives.values())
        position = val_list.index(correct_answer)
        correct_label = key_list[position]

        for label, alternative in labeled_alternatives.items():
            print(f"    {label}) {alternative}")

        while (answer_label := input("\t\nAnswer: a, b, c or d? \n\n")) not in labeled_alternatives:
            print(f"\tPlease answer one of {', '.join(labeled_alternatives.keys())}")

        answer = labeled_alternatives[answer_label]

        if answer == correct_answer:
            answers[question] = (answer, True, "\n\nGood Job!!!!\n\n")
            num_correct += 1
            # print(f"Correct:  {correct_label}) {correct_answer}")
        else:
            answers[question] = (answer, False, explanation)
            # print(f"\n\nWrong Answer:  {answer_label}) {answer}")
            # print(f"Correct Answer:  {correct_label}) {correct_answer}")

    for key, val in answers.items():
        print(key, f"\t\nYou answered: {val[0]}", f"\n\t{
              "YAY!!! You're right!!!" if val[1] else "That is unfortunately incorrect. "}\n\n{val[2]}")
    print(f"\n\n\n\n\n\nQuiz completed! You got {num_correct} out of {question_per_student} correct.")


startQuiz()




Prints
1. Who created Linux?
    a) Linus Torvalds
    b) Dennis Ritchie
    c) Ken Thompson
    d) The Linux Organization

Answer: a, b, c or d? 

a
2. Who is the founder of Microsoft?
    a) Elon Musk
    b) Jeff Bezos
    c) Bill Gates
    d) Bill Clinton

Answer: a, b, c or d? 

a
3. Who is the founder of Amazon?
    a) Bill Gates
    b) Joe Biden
    c) Jeff Bezos
    d) Elon Musk

Answer: a, b, c or d? 

a
Who created Linux? 
You answered: Linus Torvalds 
        YAY!!! You're right!!!



Good Job!!!!


Who is the founder of Microsoft? 
You answered: Elon Musk 
        That is unfortunately incorrect. 

Bill Gates and Paul Allen founded Microsoft.
Who is the founder of Amazon? 
You answered: Bill Gates 
        That is unfortunately incorrect. 

Jeff Bezos founded Amazon.






Quiz completed! You got 1 out of 3 correct.


Note

You can style it however you want.
It's best to have your questions in some JSON files and load it.
For each task, create a simple function.


Cant seem to make this part work print(key, f"\t\nYou answered: {val[0]}", f"\n\t{ 

@KirYadz Try: print(key, f"\t\nYou answered: {val[0]}", f"\n\t{'YAY!!! You are right!!!' if val[1] else 'That is unfortunately incorrect. '}\n\n{val[2]}") SEE HERE

What if the explanation will be displayed after the choosen answer? Where would the code be inserted?

Incorrect use of defaultdict
